# A couple of inequalities (explanation needed), how to show $\liminf_{k \to 0}k^{-1}\int(\nabla u - \nabla v)\nabla (T_k(b(u)-b(v))) \geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, limsup-and-liminf

Let $T_k(x) = \max\{-k, \min(x,k)\}$, a truncation function at levels $k$ and $-k$.

Let $b$ be a Lipschitz increasing function with $b(0)=0$ and $b'$ and $b^{-1}$ also Lipschitz.

I have seen it claimed that
$$\limsup_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k}\int_0^t \int_\Omega (f_1-f_2)T_k(b(u)-b(v)) \leq \int_0^t \int_{\Omega}|f_1-f_2|$$
and
$$\liminf_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u - \nabla v)\nabla (T_k(b(u)-b(v))) \geq 0.$$
Here $f_i$ are $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$ and $u$ and $v$ are in $L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

---

**My attempt:**

---

**For the first inequality:** Isn't this trivial or am I missing something? We have $\frac{1}{k}T_k \leq 1$ so isn't it immediate? Why the $\limsup$???

**For the second inequality:**
I was thinking of using the dominated convergence theorem. It is true that for all points $x,t$ such that $b(u)-b(v) \neq 0$, we have
$$\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k}(\nabla u - \nabla v)\nabla (T_k(b(u)-b(v))) = \lim_{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k}(\nabla u - \nabla v)T_k'(b(u)-b(v))\nabla (b(u)-b(v)) = 0$$
because $\lim \frac{1}{k}T'_k(x) = 0$ when $x \neq 0$.

So the limit of the integrand converges (**but I don't know where the set $\{b(u)-b(v) \neq 0\}$ is null!**). But I can't use DCT since **I cannot bound the integrand uniformly in $k$**.  Moreover the author uses a $\liminf$  so I guess this is not the right way.

Comment: Where do you got this problem?

Comment: @Tomás See http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~porretta/papers/Blanchard-Porretta-JDE.pdf, near the end of proof of Theorem A.1 in appendix.

Comment: I will leave some comments here, maybe it can help you: Take any $\epsilon>0$. If $|b(u)-b(v)|>\epsilon$ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$, then the set $A_k=\{x\in \Omega:\ |b(u)-b(v)|<k\}$ has zero measure for small $k$, therefore, we can exclude this case and we can assume that there is a set of positive measure $A\subset\Omega$, such that $b(u)=b(v)$ a.e. on $A$. As $b$ is increasing, we must conclude that $u=v$ a.e. on $A$. So, by Stamapacchia theorem, $\nabla u=\nabla v$ a.e. in $A$, which implies that the integral is zero on $A$. Maybe these considerations can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Tomás for your assistance, I will take some time to think about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, we have (as you alread observed) that $$\frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_\Omega (f_1-f_2)T_k(b(u)-b(v))\le\int_0^t\int_\Omega |f_1-f_2|.$$

From here, we need to take $\limsup$, because we don't know if the left hand side converge.

With respect to the second question, I will give a partial answer. Assume that $b^{-1}$ and $b'$ is Lipschitz (note that in the paper you are reading, they assume that $b^{-1}$ is Lipschitz, however, there is nothing about $b'$). Let $A_k=\{x\in\Omega:\ |b(u)-b(v)|<k\}$. Note that for all $k$, $$\tag{1}\int_0^t\int_\Omega (\nabla u-\nabla v)\nabla (T_k(b(u)-b(v)))=\int_0^t \int_{A_k}(\nabla u-\nabla v)( b'(u)\nabla u- b'(v)\nabla v).$$

On the other hand, as $(\nabla u-\nabla v)(\nabla u-\nabla v)\ge 0$, we conclude that (remember that $b'\ge 0$) $b'(u)\nabla u(\nabla u-\nabla v)\ge b'(u)\nabla v(\nabla u-\nabla v)$. We combine this inequality with $(1)$ to obtain

$$\tag{2}
 \frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_\Omega (\nabla u-\nabla v)\nabla (T_k(b(u)-b(v))) \ge \frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_{A_k} (\nabla u-\nabla v)\nabla v(b'(u)-b'(v)).$$

If the right hand side of $(2)$ converge to zero, we are done. Note that

$$\left|\frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_\Omega (\nabla u-\nabla v)\nabla v(b'(u)-b'(v))\right|\le \frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_{A_k} c|\nabla u-\nabla v||\nabla v||u-v|,\tag{3}$$

where $c$ is the Lipschitz constant of $b'$. As $b^{-1}$ is Lipschitz, there is a constant $C$ such that $C|u-v|\le |b(u)-b(v)|$, therefore, in the set $A_k$, we must have $|u-v|\le \frac{k}{C}$. Thus, from $(3)$

$$\left|\frac{1}{k}\int_0^t\int_\Omega (\nabla u-\nabla v)\nabla v(b'(u)-b'(v))\right|\le \int_0^t\int_{A_k} cC|\nabla u-\nabla v||\nabla v|.$$

To finish, we can just apply Lebesgue theorem.

I hope this calculation may be of some help.

Comment: Thanks Tomas for answer. If I understood your first point, we can say it like this. "If $a_n \leq C$, and if $\lim a_n$ exists, then $\lim a_n \leq C$. Otherwise the best we can do is take limsups, because $\limsup a_n$ always exists". 

With respect to the second question, I'm afraid I don't see why. I think you missed the factor of $\frac{1}{k}$ by the way there.

Comment: Maybe (after putting in the factor $\frac{1}{k}$, we can use Lebesgue differentiation theorem in some way.

Comment: You are welcome @riem. Yes, you are right, that's the idea behind the $\limsup$. Concerning the second, do you agree with that I have wrote? If so, then you have a sequence, let's say, $a_k$, which is bounded, thereforem $\frac{a_k}{k}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh sorry I understand. So all that is left is to show the RHS is bounded independent of $k$. This is because we can bound the integral by an integral over the larger set $\Omega$ instead of just $|b(u)-b(v)| \leq k$, right?

Comment: Yes that's the idea.

Comment: Hmm, I think there is a mistake with the second inequality. We are taking $k \to 0$, not to $\infty$. I will think on it..

Comment: Ops, sorry by the mistake. Let me think a little bit more and try to correct it. If I can't I will delete this answer.

Comment: Great thank you. In fact "my" $b$ has $|b''|$ bounded so this is perfect for me. I will let you know if figure out how to do non-Lipschitz case. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. So indeed, $b'$ is also Lipschitz. I would suggest to you, to write these things on your post, to make some comments about these hypothesis, so when other people come here to read, they will get a better undertanding.

Comment: Good idea, I will do so.

Comment: @Tomás Could you please explain, presumable you use Lebesgue differentiation theorem on (2). Why do you need (3) and the inequality after (3)? I don't understand why that gives convergence.